# Should users be able to migrate their own questions to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, questions, migration

It might be an idea to allow users to migrate their own questions between sites. This can for example be allowed when all the following condition match:

1. The question has a maximum of X up-votes (for example 5)<sup>1</sup>,
2. The user had a minimal reputation of X on both the source and the target site (for example 1.000)
3. The question is not older than X amount of time (for example a week).

*Sometimes I see questions that will fit way better on another site in the Stack Exchange family.*

Any thoughts on such a feature? 
*<del>Also a badge can be created for the first move and maybe others related to moving.</del>*

**Note:** The threshold will be high, because a certain number of reputation points on both sites and the amount of votes and question age will limit the range of questions that can be self-migrated. Therefore it will prevent users from massively starting to migrate questions. The reputation makes self-migration a privilege to be earned.

---

*<sup>1.</sup>  Upvotes only because a question is likely to be downvoted when asked on the wrong site. And unlikely to be upvoted on the wrong site.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To a degree, the question asker already has this control... if a user requests that their question be moved using the "In need of moderator attention" flag and the mods determine that the question is a good fit on the other site, the question is quite likely to be moved...

Or, if the question meets the deletion requirements, they can simply delete it and re-ask it on the other site, no migration necessary.

I don't know why self-migration is needed.

The badges are outright horrid ideas because then people will start intentionally asking questions on the wrong site just so they can migrate them.

Comment: Ok, good point about the badge indeed. But deleting and asking on another forum is less user friendly then asking and waiting for a mod to do it.

Comment: SE sites are not forums. Deleting and reasking is pretty easy (if you don't have any upvoted answers). Not sure what's particularly less user friendly than potentially waiting several hours for a mod to agree to a migration.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question slightly.